# Setting the default value in LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a requirement for pre-setting a field to the last entered value. I'm saving the value on `Save()` to a static and then I would like to set the field to that value the next time a new entry form is created.

I cannot get the last step ... I get entity errors saying the entity is already attached.

How can I set the value of a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the default value in the Created event on the data table. Capture the last value in the Changed event - this will capture every change that the current user makes to the field.  Here's an example using an entity called "Widget" that sets the default price to the last price entered by the user:

```
public partial class Widget
{
    private static decimal LastWidgetPrice;

    partial void Widget_Created()
    {
        Price = LastWidgetPrice;
    }

    partial void Price_Changed()
    {
        LastWidgetPrice = Price;
    }
}
```

Note that you can't capture the value in the Inserting or Updating events, because these events happen on the server, and the Created event happens on the client. Since the Changed event happens in client code, we can use that event to capture the last value entered.

The Created and Changed events can be created using the WriteCode drop-down on the entity designer (i.e. the table designer).

Comment: Yes, but how? I tried using this.DataWorkspace.Application.XYZ = LastValue; and I get exceptions.

Comment: Sorry about that! I was in a hurry last night and didn't review my answer. I've corrected the solution and included some sample code. Please let me know if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I would like to do this on the screen, not the widget. I did try it on the widget but the screen just shows up with everything greyed out (disabled).

Comment: Looks like when i add that code to the widget I can no longer add new items using any type of screen.

Comment: This is working fine for me on a simple test project. It's possible that you have some code in your screen that is causing problems. The best way to test this is to quickly generate another screen and see if your default value code is working. By the way - adding code to screens should be a last resort in LightSwitch development. It's usually much more effective to add code to data tables.

Comment: I've added a bunch of other screens and the result is the same except on the List & Details screen. Adding the code to the widget worked (using the only working screen)